# Converting a UTC date to a local time with Swift: hours added instead of hours removed

Tags: swift, timezone, nsdate

I am trying to convert a UTC date into the current timezone but I notice a time problem.

I am in **Tahiti / French Polynesia** (UTC-10) and current time (used format : yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss) is: 2018/08/05 06:45:00

Google says UTC Time is: 2018/08/**05** 16:45:00

With this code below, the result is: 2018/08/**06** 02:45:42 +0000 (the day after today) instead of 2018/08/05 06:45:42 +0000 (today).

Converting Date() to the current timezone **add 10 hours** instead of **remove 10 hours**.

*Where is my mistake ?*

**Swift 3**

```
import Foundation

    extension Date {

     var toLocalTimezone : Date {

      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
      formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:0) // UTC
      let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: self)

      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current // Local
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd' 'HH:mm:ss"

      return dateFormatter.date(from:defaultTimeZoneStr)!

      }

    }

    debugPrint("\(TimeZone.current)")
    debugPrint("Locale time : \(Date().toLocalTimezone.toFormat(format: DateFormats.yyyyMMddHHmmss))" )
```

Results :

> "Current timezone : Pacific/Tahiti (current)"
>
> "Locale time : 2018-08-06 02:45:42"

Instead of :

> "Locale time : 2018-08-05 06:45:42"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple actually. `timeZone` property of `DateFormatter` is telling the `DateFormatter` what timezone the string generated **from `Date`** should be in **OR** what timezone is the string that you are trying to convert **to `Date`**.

What it means in your case?

```
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
  formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:0) // UTC
  let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: self)
```

This means you are formatting a `Date` to a `String` and that resulting `String` will be in `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:0)`

On the other hand:

```
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current // Local
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd' 'HH:mm:ss"

  return dateFormatter.date(from:defaultTimeZoneStr)!
```

You are telling the formatter that you have a `String` in `TimeZone.current` and it will try to create a `Date` from it.

`Date` is always a GMT+0 and you are supposed to use other APIs (`DateFormatter`) to convert it to output format and timezone.

My understanding is that you are trying to create a function that will output a `Date` formatted into `String` with custom format and users timezone. Here is the snippet I believe you are looking for:

```
extension Date {
  func format(_ format: String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current // Local
    return formatter.string(from: self)
  }
}
```